# "End of line expected" error preventing me from opening game

Tags: python, renpy

I wanted to open my game to check that everything is working properly, but whenever I try to open the project, it redirects me to the script instead. This is the message below:

> I'm sorry, but errors were detected in your script. Please correct the errors listed below, and try again.
>
> ```
> File "game/script.rpy", line 388: end of line expected.
>    jump skip:
>             ^
> Ren'Py Version: Ren'Py 7.4.11.2266
> Sat Jun  4 21:37:05 2022
> ```

(For reference, I'm trying to skip some dialogue that's only available once you're on the normal ending. I've attached a picture to help) [image: game script screenshot]

I tried indenting it with one-two lines, putting all the dialogue after the indention line and putting the label skip: on a different indention line, but none of it has worked.

How do I fix this?

Comment: 1) Code should be included with the code format, not as an image. 2) if you blank out almost all code, are you sure that no error is in the code you are hiding? 3) include the minimum code needed to get the exact same error. If the hidden lines are not needed for producing the error, remove them in your question

Comment: The error says line 388, and says it looks like this `jump skip:`. However, reading the image we see a `jump skip` (the `:` is missing) and it is on the line 396.

Answer (score 2):

This error:

> ```
> File "game/script.rpy", line 388: end of line expected.
>    jump skip:
>             ^
> Ren'Py Version: Ren'Py 7.4.11.2266
> Sat Jun  4 21:37:05 2022
> ```

This is telling me that the line 388 of the file "game/script.rpy" looks like this:

```
   jump skip:
```

*Said line 388 is not included in the attached image, which goes from line 395 to 436.*

The cause of the error is that you should not put a `:` on a `jump`. The `:` is for code blocks, but `jump` isn't one.

The reiterate the error message: the parser was expecting that the line ended, but instead of that, it found a `:`.